# skip_before_filter ignores conditionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to use skip_before_filter only if the app is in production mode. (I don't want my development instances public, and I want the app to automatically detect what type of instance it is on and display a log-in screen when it is not in production mode). So, my application controller has the following line:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => "sign_in" #redirects to log-in
```

And the controller for displaying pages has this line:

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :show, :if => :in_production
#public pages are public, but only when in production.
```

And in_production is simply:

```
  def in_production
    ENV['RAILS_ENV']=='production'
  end
```

I realize that there may be other avenues here, but I'm curious as to why skip_before_filter seems to ignore the conditional and always just skip the before_filter. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Using Rails 2.3.9 and the Devise authentication gem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is a Rails bug (or at least an undocumented strange behaviour). It is tracked here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9703

In this thread, you can find a (twisted) solution.

Instead of

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :show, :if => :in_production
```

write

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :show
before_filter      :authenticate_user!, :only => :show, :unless => :in_production
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I have found that the solution posted by SmartLove in the described scenario presents a kind of security hole or an unexpected behaviour. The line

`before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :show, :unless => :in_production`

because of the `:only => :show`, is **overriding** the existing before_filter defined in the ApplicationController. That means that all the actions of this controller (e.g :edit, :create, etc.), except the :show one, will be omitting the authenticate_user! filter.

A possible solution is removing the :only clause and checking the action called inside the conditional method. For example:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :unless => :skip_filter?

def skip_filter?
  params[:action] == "show" && in_production
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure `skip_before_filter` accepts an `:if` parameter, so I'd try this syntax

```
(skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:show]) if in_production
```

If it still doesn't work, try putting this in your application controller

```
if ENV['RAILS_ENV']=='production'
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :show
end
```

Comment: That first example works. If it doesn't accept an :if param, why is it silent about it?

Comment: `skip_before_filter` takes a `*filters` array splat, so it can't tell if there are invalid arguments. I imagine that when the splat is treated, the invalid hash keys are ignored (or not retrieved).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got around this issue.

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :if => { action_name == 'show' && in_production }
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9703#issuecomment-223574827