# Is there a way in Rails to skip a before_filter if the request is xhr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With the following code :

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :load_something,      # how to skip these only 
                     :load_something_else  # if the request is xhr ?

  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

end
```

Is there a way to skip before filters depending if the request is a javascript call without changing the `:load_something` and `:load_something_else` methods ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There used to be no clean solution to this. Assuming you do not have control over the `before_filters` (or do not want to change them), i would leave the `skip_before_filter` and add an extra `before_filter` that only executes the wanted methods if it is an `xhr` method.

So something like

```
skip_before_filter :load_something,      # how to skip these only 
                   :load_something_else  # if the request is xhr ?
before_filter :do_loads_if_xhr

def do_loads_if_xhr
  if request.xhr?
    load_something
    load_something_else
  end
end
```

The method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637110/skip-before-filter-ignores-conditionals) only works because the conditional is global for the application: the conditional is only evaluated when the class is created. Not on each request.

[UPDATED]
There is however, a cleaner way to make the `skip_before_filter` conditional. Write it like this:

```
skip_before_filter :load_something, :load_something_else, :if => proc {|c| request.xhr?}
```

Also note that while `skip_before_filter` is still completely supported, and not deprecated, since rails 4 the documentation seems to prefer the (identical) `skip_before_action`. Also the documentation is totally not clear about this, had to verify in code.

Answer (score 40):

Try this line to skip the filtering by a condition:

```
skip_before_filter :load_something, :load_something_else,
   :if => proc { request.xhr? }
```

For [ruby-2.0](/questions/tagged/ruby-2.0) you can also use lambdas (which have a strictness in argument passing):

```
skip_before_filter :load_something, :load_something_else,
   if: -> { request.xhr? }
```

or with an argument:

```
skip_before_filter :load_something, :load_something_else,
   if: ->(arg) { request.xhr? && arg }
```

Answer (score 14):

All of these answers take the wrong approach in my opinion. Using a skip_before_action with a condition is doing it backwards, and isn't as explicit and clear as adding the condition to the before_action itself; so this is my proposal:

```
before_action :require_password_change, unless: -> { request.xhr? }
```

This way, to someone reading your code it's immediately clear under what conditions this before_action runs or doesn't run, without having to rely on them happening across this skip_before_action somewhere in the controller hierarchy.

Comment: this is the best approach I've seen

Comment: It seems this is nowhere really documented, but this actually comes from the `ActiveSupport::Callbacks` class.

Answer (score 4):

Use `alias_method_chain` to decorate the filters, so they aren't executed if the request is xhr.

```
def load_something_with_noxhr(*args)
  load_something_without_noxhr(*args) unless request.xhr?
end

alias_method_chain :load_something, :noxhr
```

(change `load_something` into whatever needed, the `_with_` and `_without_` are literal, and the suffix `noxhr` must be the same you pass as second argument in the `alias_method_chain` call.)

Comment: Looks like `alias_method_chain` might be deprecated / not recommended http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689736/rails-3-alias-method-chain-still-used

Comment: Not that it's not recommended, but now (Ruby 2.1) there is the marvellos `prepend MyModule` which puts your module _in front_ of the call chain, so the funcion in the module can actually call `super` and call the same-named funcion in the "including" class.

Answer (score 3):

You coded that filters? In that case you can write an `if` clause inside them without using `skip_before_filter`:

```
def load_something
  unless request.xhr?
    #Code
  end
end
```

In the other hand, you can make yout own filter and delegate:

```
before_filter :my_own_filter

def my_own_filter
  unless request.xhr?
    load_something
    load_something_else
  end
end
```

I think this should work.

Comment: Shouldn't the methods be &&'d together so that if a previous one returns false then the others won't run and the filter chain will be halted?