# conditionally skip_before_filter while preserving filter order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

To conditionally skip a `before_filter`, I have used Rafa Paez's suggested solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21755636/1348146

My ApplicationController contains the following method:

```
  def self.skip_authentication_if_json_request_for(*actions)
    skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
    can_skip_authentication_check = lambda do
      request.format.json? && actions.include?(params[:action].to_sym)
    end
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, unless: can_skip_authentication_check
  end
```

Subcontrollers then specify that user authentication can be skipped for certain actions by including:

```
  skip_authentication_if_json_request_for :index
```

I'm very happy with this approach because it is DRY and a very readable one-liner for each subcontroller, but my main problem is that the order of the `before_filter`s is modified. With this one-liner, the order is:

```
[:filter-a, :filter-b, filter-c, :authenticate_user!]
```

but without, the location of `authenticate-user!` is different:

```
[:filter-a, :authenticate_user!, :filter-b, :filter-c]
```

How do I ensure that the modified `before-filter :authenticate-user!` is inserted at the original location?

Comment: Check this question and see if it can be of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711797/how-can-i-specify-the-order-that-before-filters-are-executed

Comment: Yes, someone there links to http://b2.broom9.com/?p=806, which does provide a solution, but not one I'm really satisfied with. I could do `skip_before_filter :filter-a` followed by `prepend_before_filter :filter-a, :authenticate_user!`, but then I would silently drop any `:if`, `:only`, `:unless` and other modifiers from the original `before_filter :filter-a`